# What is the purpose of WAAS?

Tags: approach, waas

Does it just help with all of the approaches like LPV and stuff? Or is it its own thing?

Comment: Have you read through the FAA's [WAAS description and benefits](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/techops/navservices/gnss/waas)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Global Navigation Satellite Systems (GNSS), e.g. GPS, have a statistical accuracy of about 100m, and it’s particularly bad in the vertical dimension. This imposed severe limitations on how close older RNAV approaches (now called LNAV) could let you get to terrain and obstacles.

Satellite-Based Augmentation Systems (SBAS), e.g. WAAS, improve that accuracy to about 10m. Less position error, especially in the vertical dimension, means you can safely be much closer to terrain and obstacles, which led to new classes of RNAV approaches with much lower minima, e.g. LPV.

SBAS also counts as an extra GNSS satellite for Receiver Autonomous Integrity Monitoring (RAIM) purposes, so an SBAS-equipped aircraft may be able to fly in places/times where a non-augmented GNSS aircraft can’t see enough satellites.

Comment: So you're saying it could get you lower minimums?

Comment: WAAS includes a ground component (GBAS) providing corrections to GPS signals for atmospheric delays due to, e.g., expansion of the ionosphere from solar activity.

Comment: @FosterBoondoggle GBAS is LAAS. Do not confuse the WAAS ground stations for GBAS.

Comment: SBAS improves Accuracy and Availability, indeed, but the game changer for aviation is the introduction of **Integrity**, and enabling integrity monitoring for aviation receivers. That is key for the approval of automated landing based on GNSS.

Comment: @FosterBoondoggle do you have a source that the ground component of WAAS is called GBAS?  I have never seen it called that for WAAS.  I always thought GBAS was specifically regarding the GLS ground component, not the WAAS ground component.

Comment: Regarding "older RNAV approaches (now called LNAV)" -> isn't the approach still called RNAV? LNAV is just one of the three types of minima (others being LNAV/VNAV and LPV), right?

Comment: Too bad the technology lags so far behind commercial and consumer technology.  Thanks to an antenna developed several years ago (at U of Texas IIRC) that allowed GPS receivers in cell phones to locate position in 3 dimensions to within centimeters, which has made the whole drone delivery concept feasible.  I can only imagine the time and cost to certify that kind of capability for an aviation system.

Comment: @JohnK In practice, the accuracy of even non-augmented GPS is far better than the statistical models predict. But that’s the number ICAO et al insist on using for manned aircraft.  It comes down to the various errors usually canceling out, whereas the models assume the worst case of additive errors.

Comment: @StephenS & Ryan M - I thought I had a source but I can't find it & maybe I misread. Per the FAA you are right that it's specific to local landing system enhancement. "A Ground Based Augmentation System (GBAS) augments the existing Global Positioning System (GPS) used in U.S. airspace by providing corrections to aircraft in the vicinity of an airport..." My comment was meant to observe that WAAS has ground component, which the reply to the OP implied was purely satellite based. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @FosterBoondoggle: "*WAAS includes a ground component (GBAS) providing corrections to GPS signals*", no GBAS and SBAS are two systems using permanent ground GNSS receivers to compute GNSS corrections and check GNSS integrity. The difference is a SBAS (e.g. WAAS or EGNOS) broadcasts corrections and integrity data via GEO satellites, and a GBAS via VHF ground stations. In both cases, corrections and integrity data are determined by comparing the GNSS positions with the known positions of the receiving stations.